# Solving a differential equation in $x^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}=x^{-n}-2x$$
for $x(t)$ over the interval $0<x<\infty$ for $n>0$ and $x(1)=1$.

I have got to the following by multiplying both sides by $x^n$ and changing variables:
$$x^n=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-e^{-2n(t+k_1)}\right) \text{ where }k_1\text{ is a constant}$$

However I am not sure how to find $x(t)$ from this. Do I set n=1, or do I need to substitute this back into the original equation? What does the '$n>0$' mean in relation to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral of  $\frac{x^{n}dx}{1-2x^{n+1}}$ is:

$-\frac{ln(2x^{n+1}-1}{2(n+1)}=t+t_{0}$.

By imposing the conditions $x(1)=1$, just substitute $t=1$ and $x=1$:

$-\frac{ln(2.1^{n+1}-1}{2(n+1)}=1+t_{0}$,

from which we have:

$t_{0}=-1$.

The solution is:

$x(t)=2^{\frac{-1}{n+1}}.e^{-2t}(e^{ 2(n+1)t}+e^{2(n+1)})^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\dot x=\frac{1}{x^n}-2x\iff \frac{1}{-2(n+1)}\cdot \frac{-2(n+1)x^n \dot x}{1-2x^{n+1}}=1.$$

Comment: Thanks! This is what I did to find $x^n$, by making the substitution $u=1-2x^{n+1}$, so $\text{d}u=-2(n+1)x^n\text{d}x$. I am not sure how I can go from $x^n$ to $x(t)$ though, which is what I need to find

Comment: just take the $n-$th square root... @mp12853